# how to enable remote shell with embedded db on SDN4?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Hi I'm using the following configuration

```
 driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver
 URI=file:///data/graph
```

in `ogm.properties` file

how can i enable remote shell with it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to pass custom configuration to the embedded driver. Please feel free to open a feature request at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues

Comment: thank you, is there another approach i can use to reach the goal? without this feature embedded db is not really production ready imho.
I created an issue at [link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/134)

thanks for your time

Comment: Unfortunately not till the issue you logged is resolved.